# IONIC video and audio loop

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
 <video id="testvideo" src="data/videoteste.webm" class="video" loop="loop" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">
         </video>
```

I want you to always play the same video / audio, the first time you play it, you do everything right, from the second time you only play the video and the audio does not work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Add your code!!

Comment: done, sorry for that

Comment: Add your error.

Comment: my problem is that the second time the video will play does not give the sound